# Use database (such as sqlite) with cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode4, cocos2d-x

I am starting to build a gaming application on iphone. I am using cocos2d-x game engine, since it is easy to port to android from there. Also the coding is in C++, which I am very much familiar with. I want to know if there is a way to use any database with cocos2d-x. Although sqlite is preferred but not mandatory. I will have about 1/2 mb of data in the database. So, yes I have thought about keeping/using an in-memory database too, but I want my read/write queries to be time efficient.

I have looked up at some of blogs, which suggest that I may need to use a C++ wrapper for sqlite. The problem is, for an independent C++ code, I can setup the environment, but how do I integrate this in xcode (in mac os) to use sqlite with cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 2):

original post is at http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/7006

I found that a easiest way to include sqlite to cocos2dx game.

That is, download the source code from sqlite3 c++ api, and add sqlite3.c to Android.mk.

Then compile these code as your cocos2dx code.

and include the sqlite.h in yourcode when you need to use it.

For operation on database following is my sample code:

```
sqlite3 *pDB = NULL;
char* errMsg = NULL;
string sqlstr;
int result;
string dbPath = CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath();
dbPath.append("Settings.db");
result = sqlite3_open(dbPath.c_str(),&pDB);
if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    CCLOG("OPENING WRONG, %d, MSG:%s",result,errMsg);

bool isExisted_;
sqlstr = "select count(type) from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='YourTableName'";
result = sqlite3_exec(pDB, sqlstr.c_str(), isExisted, &isExisted_, &errMsg);
if(result != SQLITE_OK)
    CCLOG("check exist fail %d Msg: %s", result, errMsg);
result = sqlite3_exec(pDB, "create table YourTableName(ID INTEGER primary key autoincrement, name varchar(32), type INT, posX INT, posY INT, isUnlock INT)",NULL,NULL,&errMsg);
if(result != SQLITE_OK)
    CCLOG("CREATE TABLE FAIL %d, Msg: %s",result,errMsg);
sqlite3_close(pDB);
```

Comment: you say "Sqlite c++ api" but I did find anything on Sqlite site that reflected that and the download file I get form them is C (hence the .c) not c++.  Am I missing something or are they one in the same

Comment: @owengerig it's my problem. it actually is c, you can use it without any problem in c++ code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is:

- Open file with [CCFileUtils::getFileData()](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d0/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_file_utils.html#aaf686ba03bdddab83741cb1ae9732b17) you will get your file data.
  For example your sqlite file :)
- Use [CCFileUtils::getWriteablePath()](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d0/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_file_utils.html#ad8723a069e1c73a79feefe260410877d) to get directory where you can write.
- Write your data to previous directory for example with [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/fstream/)
- Now you can access to your database with source code from [sqlite3 c++](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) api.

The whole topis is here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/7006

Example code :)

```
CCFileUtils* fileUtils = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils();
unsigned long size = 5;

unsigned char* smth;
smth = fileUtils->getFileData("koalalocker","r",&size);

printf("Size: %lu\n\n",size);
fflush(stdout);

if(cos == NULL)
    {
    LOG("can't open");
            return;
    }
else
    LOG("I have something!");

string path = fileUtils->getWriteablePath();
path += "test_OUT";

char buffer[300];
sprintf(buffer,"PATH: %s\n",path.c_str());
LOG(buffer);
std::fstream outfile(path.c_str(),std::fstream::out);
outfile.write((const char*)smth,size-1);
outfile.close();

LOGN("Size:",size);
LOG((const char*)smth);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog regarding integration of sqlite in a cocos2d-x game in xcode step by step. You can see this 
http://sqlite-integration-in-cocos2d-x.blogspot.in/

Comment: SQLite is already integrated in Android and IOS, you need just the reference it into your project.

Comment: @ChaleCS Things are bit different in cocos2d-x bro. If you want to use only c++ and cocos2d-x framework to achieve sqlite integration without going into native ios (obj c) and android (java) code, then this blog will help.