# How to use sqlite database in cocos creator javascript

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cocoscreator

I want to use a local database file such as question database for my quiz game. I can't find any tutorial on official cocos creator site or forums. In c++ already solved the problem 
[Use database (such as sqlite) with cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307404/use-database-such-as-sqlite-with-cocos2d-x)

But I want to use it with below javascript, which is the default script in Cocos creator

```
cc.Class({
extends: cc.Component,

properties: {
    // foo: {
    //    default: null,      // The default value will be used only when the component attaching
    //                           to a node for the first time
    //    url: cc.Texture2D,  // optional, default is typeof default
    //    serializable: true, // optional, default is true
    //    visible: true,      // optional, default is true
    //    displayName: 'Foo', // optional
    //    readonly: false,    // optional, default is false
    // },
    // ...
},

// use this for initialization
onLoad: function () {

},

onbuttnclick: function(){
    //var test = new cc.Scene('test');
    //cc.director.pushScene(test);
    cc.director.loadScene('helloworld');
    //cc.director.popScene();
},

// called every frame, uncomment this function to activate update callback
// update: function (dt) {

// },
});
```

I need a solution in javascript because I am poor in c++

Answer (score 1):

in cocoscreator  it have local saved api  like h5 localstorage.set get  parameter is key value and  key  i forgot the  api  but the  point is that  it  like   h5  localstorage api  and  it would auto use sqlite  in native

Comment: sorry adout the first command. cause i use the phone to reply without code.  now i check the code that you can use it as follow:`cc.sys.localStorage.setItem("key","value");
        let value = cc.sys.localStorage.getItem("key");`  you can storage any JSON.stringify(JSONObject); as the value in the localStorage and get it any time you restart the game if you do not delete the data file at disk in native  or local cache in chrome.